# Detecting what changes in a React/Redux store and perform actions based on the specific change

Tags: javascript, php, json, reactjs, redux

I am trying to determine if redux is necessary for this project or not.
I have a JS project that uses react to display a table of results fetched through an API.

The API produces a JSON array of users such as this **(below)** which is fetched by my React page every 10 seconds

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "email": "bdudson0@arstechnica.com",
  "online": false,
  "paid": true
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "email": "srodear1@seattletimes.com",
  "online": true,
  "paid": true
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "email": "mwillmont2@nytimes.com",
  "online": true,
  "paid": false
}]
```

This JSON array could change at any time once fetched. So for example it could reveal an extra user, reveal a deleted user, change the online status of one user to true or false and so on.

Since in the context of redux, you have actions being dispatched to a store which changes the store; this scenario (which seems to be the reverse) uses only one action which is the fetch JSON action. Also, I believe the store should be the JSON array being fetched each time. How do I detect changes to the store so that I can perform actions based on it.

So if the JSON is fetched and my react app takes the JSON as the initial state / store then fetches the JSON again, the store will be updated to the new state. I will need to be able to detect all the changes between the new and old state and perform animations based on the specific changes.

e.g. 4 changes to the state could yield the following actions which I will animate via react:

1. USER_ADDED
2. USER_ONLINE_STATUS_CHANGED
3. USER_PAYMENT_STATUS_CHANGED
4. USER_REMOVED

Is redux suitable for this? I will be working with much larger arrays and will need to know a convenient way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

> "I am trying to determine if redux is necessary for this project or not. I have a JS project that uses react to display a table of results fetched through an API."

Implement Redux only if you're going to need the state, in this case JSON array, persistent throughout the whole React application. Otherwise just handle the API calls and changes within the component. When you switch components you'll lose the state because it's not persistent between components. That's what Redux solves.

> "I will need to be able to detect all the changes between the new and old state and perform animations based on the specific changes. "

Redux will be able to handle updating the state with using both action creators and reducers. Action creators will call the API and will send the response to the  reducers. The reducers then will update, change, or delete items from the state.

> "Is redux suitable for this? I will be working with much larger arrays and will need to know a convenient way to achieve this."

It kinda does sound like Redux would be good for this project. Use it only if you need the state throughout the whole React application.

Answer (score 0):

Redux won't help you to diff the two states automatically. Basically, you will need to manually create a function to do this.

An easy way is to convert your JSON array to es6 set with

```
const set1 = new Set(OLD_STATE);
const set2 = new Set(NEW_STATE);
```

then you can call `difference()` to get the changes between these two states:

```
set1.difference(set2)
```

Alternatively, you can use `redux-diff-logger` or `redux-dev-tools` to output the diffs in your console.